# Automated marker size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a matplotlib plot where the number of points doesn't have any such restrictions, i.e. I can plot 1K points as well as 1M points.

This creates a problem while choosing the markersize. The plot becomes messy when #points is large and too sparse when #points is small.

Is there a way matplotlib automatically adjusts the best fit marker size for me? I'm asking since matplotlib can automatically adjust the optimal legend location for me, so maybe it can find the optimal markersize as well.

```
ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', markersize=0.05, linestyle='None')
```

Now, I've two set of [#points, markersize] tuple where the markersize is appropriate. They are [1000, 0.5] and [100000, 0.05].

I've made a function out of these two points, but it's not working properly.

Comment: If you are plotting a lot of points, you might be better off with a package like datashader https://datashader.org/index.html#

Comment: Great suggestion. I didn't know about datashader earlier. I've tried datashader to plot 1M+ points, the results are good. However there are some issues with background colors and color maps which I'm figuring out. Thanks @RuthC

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example data
x = np.random.rand(1000)  # Sample x values
y = np.random.rand(1000)  # Sample y values

# Function to calculate marker size based on the number of points
def calculate_marker_size(num_points):
    # Define the minimum and maximum marker sizes
    min_marker_size = 1.0
    max_marker_size = 10.0
    
    # Define the range of points where marker size varies
    min_points = 1000
    max_points = 100000
    
    # Calculate the marker size based on a linear interpolation
    if num_points <= min_points:
        return min_marker_size
    elif num_points >= max_points:
        return max_marker_size
    else:
        # Linear interpolation between min and max marker sizes
        slope = (max_marker_size - min_marker_size) / (max_points - min_points)
        return min_marker_size + slope * (num_points - min_points)

# Calculate marker size based on the number of points
marker_size = calculate_marker_size(len(x))

# Create the plot with dynamic marker size
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=marker_size, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('Scatter Plot with Dynamic Marker Size')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

In this example, the calculate_marker_size function takes the number of points as input and calculates the marker size using linear interpolation between a minimum and maximum marker size. You can adjust the min_marker_size, max_marker_size, min_points, and max_points values to customize the behavior according to your preferences.

This approach dynamically adjusts the marker size based on the number of points in your data, allowing for a more visually appealing plot, whether you have a small or large number of data points.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but linear extrapolation is not working here. It becomes too messy. In addition to linear extrapolation, I've tried the exponential version too, with slightly better results. 

As of now, I'm using this
```
base_marker_size = 10
markersize = base_marker_size / np.sqrt(points)
```
Results are manageable, works best at around 1M points.

Comment: This looks like it was written by chatGPT. Note the help centre advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy